C# Json Deserialize Dynamic Type
We have a C# Console Application that calls several 3rd party API's. We get the data from these API's back in JSON format. We are trying to deserialize the JSON into a defined class. The issue is that the 'custom_attributes' property in the json contains objects with the following structure:
{
    ...other properties
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "required_options",
            "value": "simple"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "category_ids",
            "value": [
                "2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "has_options",
            "value": "0"
        }
    ]
}

As you can see, the 'value' property can have a "string" type, or a "string[]" type as the value.
Currently, we have the following code:
public class MyApiResponseClass 
{
    ... other properties
    [JsonProperty("custom_attributes")]
    public List<CustomAttribute> CustomAttributes { get; set; } = new();
}

public class CustomAttribute
{
    [JsonProperty("attribute_code")]
    public string AttributeCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyApiResponseClass>(responseContent);

This produces the following error:

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Object' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path 'items[0].custom_attributes[17].value', line 1, position 3119.'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

have you tried the "dynamic" type instead of object?

Hi @Grantly, I have. It actually produces the exact same error message.

The exception seems to be thrown because you are pre-initializing your Value property to a string:
public object Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

If I remove the initial value the exception goes away:
public class CustomAttribute
{
    [JsonProperty("attribute_code")]
    public string AttributeCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; } // = string.Empty;
}

Demo fiddle #1 here.
Presumably you don't want that, but it appears marking the property with ObjectCreationHandling.Replace also makes the problem go away:
public class CustomAttribute
{
    [JsonProperty("attribute_code")]
    public string AttributeCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonProperty("value", ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)]
    public object Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

Since you are already annotating your model with Newtonsoft attributes, this seems like the least disruptive fix.  Demo fiddle #2 here.
And finally, adding a parameterized constructor that takes the attribute code and value and marking it with [JsonConstructor] also resolves the exception:
public class CustomAttribute
{
    public CustomAttribute() { }
    [JsonConstructor]
    public CustomAttribute(string attributeCode, object value) => (this.AttributeCode, this.Value) = (attributeCode, value);

    // Remainder unchanged

Demo fiddle #3 here.
I can't really explain this exception, you might want to raise an issue here with Newtonsoft.
